# Table layout did not show data from Firebase database (Android)

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am not able to show any data from my Firebase database on my dynamic table layout.

I want it to be created the moment I am in the page view. I have created a function to call when the if-condition is true.

Can I know if I have done wrong anywhere?

I have declared two database listener for two different references.

```
final DatabaseReference priceLevel = placeRef.child("price_level/"+ estBudget+"/");
    priceLevel.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                placeObj place = dataSnapshot.getValue(placeObj.class); //get value from firebase?

                Log.d(TAG, "I am inside the find place to eat event listener."); //this log did not even appear in the console.

                for (int i = 0; i <= Integer.valueOf(days); i++) {

                    TextView place_name = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    place_name.setText(place.getPlace_name());
                    place_name.setTextSize(20);
                    place_name.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5f));
                    place_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Place name: " + place_name);

                    TextView place_type = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    place_type.setText("Description" + place.getPlace_type());
                    place_type.setTextSize(20);
                    place_type.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5f));
                    place_type.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    TextView price_range = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    price_range.setText("SGD$ " + place.getPrice_range());
                    price_range.setTextSize(20);
                    price_range.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5f));
                    price_range.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    TextView vegan_type = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    vegan_type.setText("Vegan friendly:" + place.getVegan_type());
                    vegan_type.setTextSize(20);
                    vegan_type.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5f));
                    vegan_type.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    TextView website = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    website.setText("Website: " + Html.fromHtml(place.getWebsite()));
                    website.setTextSize(20);
                    website.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5f));
                    website.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                    row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    row.addView(place_name);
                    row.addView(place_type);
                    row.addView(price_range);
                    row.addView(vegan_type);
                    row.addView(website);

                    tblLocation.addView(row);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

This is the output I am receiving that prohibited me from entering onDataChange:

[image]

Comment: Add your firebase data base or nodes reference and did you verified you are getting result at - placeObj place = dataSnapshot.getValue(placeObj.class);?

Comment: @Rasi sorry sir, I could not even enter doDataChange()

Comment: Where are those references and add your add. Atleast screeshot

Comment: I have solved it. Issue likes on the json file which I have created myself.